# How to choose the correct IMediaEncodingProperties from GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo) from MediaCapture?

Tags: windows-8, camera, windows-runtime

I used

```
IReadOnlyList<IMediaEncodingProperties> supportedResolutions = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo)
```

to get resolutions.

So that i got 40 IMediaEncodingProperties.
In that first 18 IMediaEncodingProperties has Subtype as "YUY2", next 22 has Subtype "MJPG".

We will get 4 IMediaEncodingProperties for same resolution like for **640 × 480**

First **IMediaEncodingProperties**

```
    -       supportedResolutions[0] {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties} Windows.Media.MediaProperties.IMediaEncodingProperties {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties}
    -       [Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties] {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties} Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties
            Bitrate 147456000   uint
    -       FrameRate   {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio}  Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio
            Denominator 1   uint
            Numerator   30  uint
            Height  480 uint
    +       PixelAspectRatio    {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio}  Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio
            ProfileId   0   int
    +       Properties  {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet}    Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet
            Subtype "YUY2"  string
            Type    "Video" string
            Width   640 uint
    +       Properties  {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet}    Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet
            Subtype "YUY2"  string
            Type    "Video" string
```

Second **IMediaEncodingProperties**

```
-       supportedResolutions[1] {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties} Windows.Media.MediaProperties.IMediaEncodingProperties {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties}
-       [Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties] {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties} Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties
        Bitrate 147456000   uint
-       FrameRate   {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio}  Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio
        Denominator 1   uint
        Numerator   15  uint
        Height  480 uint
+       PixelAspectRatio    {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio}  Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio
        ProfileId   0   int
+       Properties  {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet}    Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet
        Subtype "YUY2"  string
        Type    "Video" string
        Width   640 uint
+       Properties  {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet}    Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet
        Subtype "YUY2"  string
        Type    "Video" string
```

19th **IMediaEncodingProperties**

```
-       supportedResolutions[18]    {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties} Windows.Media.MediaProperties.IMediaEncodingProperties {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties}
-       [Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties] {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties} Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties
        Bitrate 221184000   uint
-       FrameRate   {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio}  Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio
        Denominator 1   uint
        Numerator   30  uint
        Height  480 uint
-       PixelAspectRatio    {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio}  Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio
        Denominator 1   uint
        Numerator   1   uint
        ProfileId   0   int
+       Properties  {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet}    Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet
        Subtype "MJPG"  string
        Type    "Video" string
        Width   640 uint
+       Properties  {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet}    Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet
        Subtype "MJPG"  string
        Type    "Video" string
```

20th **IMediaEncodingProperties**

```
-       supportedResolutions[19]    {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties} Windows.Media.MediaProperties.IMediaEncodingProperties {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties}
-       [Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties] {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties} Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingProperties
        Bitrate 221184000   uint
-       FrameRate   {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio}  Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio
        Denominator 1   uint
        Numerator   15  uint
        Height  480 uint
+       PixelAspectRatio    {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio}  Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaRatio
        ProfileId   0   int
+       Properties  {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet}    Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet
        Subtype "MJPG"  string
        Type    "Video" string
        Width   640 uint
+       Properties  {Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet}    Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaPropertySet
        Subtype "MJPG"  string
        Type    "Video" string
```

What is the differents between these IMediaEncodingProperties. What should i use to capture a still photo?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the only difference between those four are their Numerators and Bitrate.  I am not sure if either of those properties come into play with Photo as I'd associate them only with video but to be safe perhaps grab the one with the largest bitrate and largest numerator/denominator ratio.